# Ordering results of MySQL query (using join)

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

In a WordPress installation, I need to order products so that:

1. Sold products show up last.
2. Sold products tagged "antique" show up after sold products tagged "reproduction."

I have successfully completed the first item, but I am at a loss regarding the second item. I'm not getting any errors. My problem is that everything in my ORDER BY statement is working except for "wt.slug DESC." If I change the LEFT JOIN statements for wp_term_taxonomy and wp_terms tables to INNER JOIN statements, I get 0 results, so it looks to me like these statements are not finding the results that I expect. Here is my query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID 
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta stock ON ( wp_posts.ID = stock.post_id AND stock.meta_key = '_stock_status' ) 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy wtt ON ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wtt.term_taxonomy_id AND wtt.taxonomy = 'product_tag' ) 
LEFT JOIN wp_terms wt ON ( wtt.term_id = wt.term_id AND ( wt.slug = 'antique' OR wt.slug = 'reproduction' ) ) 
WHERE 1=1 
AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (171) ) 
AND ( ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_visibility' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) IN ('visible','catalog') ) ) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_type DESC, stock.meta_value ASC, wt.slug DESC, wp_posts.post_date
```

Here is the [WordPress database description](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description) for reference. I would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: What error message and/or output are you getting?  It's a bit hard to digest the query with little knowledge of the Wordpress schema.

Comment: I've updated my question to clarify exactly what I'm having trouble with, and I linked to the database description (with an image of the schema).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to help from @mynawaz, I have been able to come up with a solution. I'm not sure if it's the most efficient or elegant solution, but it works:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.* , CASE wt.slug WHEN 'antique' THEN 1 WHEN 'reproduction' THEN 2 ELSE 0 END as slug_order 
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta stock ON ( wp_posts.ID = stock.post_id AND stock.meta_key = '_stock_status' ) 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships wtr ON ( wp_posts.ID = wtr.object_id AND stock.meta_value = 'outofstock' ) 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy wtt ON ( wtr.term_taxonomy_id = wtt.term_taxonomy_id AND wtt.taxonomy = 'product_tag' ) 
LEFT JOIN wp_terms wt ON ( wtt.term_id = wt.term_id AND wt.slug IN( 'antique','reproduction' ) ) 
WHERE 1=1 
AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (171) ) 
AND ( ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_visibility' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) IN ('visible','catalog') ) ) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
AND NOT ( 
    stock.meta_value = 'outofstock' 
    AND ( CASE wt.slug WHEN 'antique' THEN 1 WHEN 'reproduction' THEN 2 ELSE 0 END ) = 0 
) 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID, slug_order 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_type DESC, stock.meta_value ASC, slug_order DESC, wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new field as

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID, CASE wt.slug WHEN 'antique' THEN -1 WHEN 'reproduction' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as sort_order
```

and use the `sort_order` in `ORDER BY` clause like

```
ORDER BY sort_order DESC
```

Comment: This is a neat way to order what I need, but it doesn't solve my problem of the JOIN statements not working for the wp_terms and wp_term_taxonomy tables.